# Error with Initial commit to github for my unity project

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get some version control for my project and git isn't exactly working well for that. I've been trying to figure out git for months and i finally got my unity project in a git folder with meta files enabled and now I get this error when i try to initially commit it to the master server:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Unity GUI for git commit. I have never used unity framework. but I think following troubleshooting my help you.

- Open root directory of your git repo
- press shift and right click and open command prompt
  then use following commands
- *`git status`*  it will show you all tracked files that have changes
- *`git add file1 file2 file3`* . . .  add all your files you want to commit
- *`git commit`*    it will commit and open a text editor inside command prompt for you to enter commit message. after entering commit press escape, then enter : and write wq and enter.
- *`git log`* it will show you all commits, your commit should be on top.

This method should do your commit.

Comment: Yea that's actually just github open in another window lol. The screenshot is a little misleasing. So github has problems committing a ton of files at once? Or is it just because I'm trying to send unsupported files and assets? I need some form of version control and this should also allow me to have multiple people work on this project if I ever plan in doing that.

Comment: github doesnot have any kind of problem commiting several files, check if your are commiting some binary files ? 
A helful site https://www.gitignore.io/ may help you to generate a .gitignore file that are not necessary to commit on upstream.